# Consuming huge partitions in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am consuming a huge topic with 50 partitions with overall 10M records.So,I am expecting 200000 per partition .I have used a simple partitioner with round robin method to allocate the 10M over 50 partitions.

When I run my consumer group,I see the data is way less than 200K in each thread and in some threads ,I am not getting even a single message to consume.Am I missing something?

Overall I get somewhere between ~800k to 1.3M only

This is my consumer config

```
props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "60000");
props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "2000");
props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
props.put("consumer.timeout.ms", "5000");
props.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");
props.put("session.timeout.ms", "5000");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I run my consumer group,I see the data is way less than 200K in
>   each thread and in some threads ,I am not getting even a single
>   message to consume.Am I missing something?
>
> Overall I get somewhere between ~800k to 1.3M

What do you exactly mean by less than 200K consumption ? 
How long did you leave your consumer code running. Depending on the client ,settings (broker & consumers) and your setup (eg: message size), it might be the case that you are running out of CPU at the consumer side and thus there is a much higher latency. What does the numbers that you report actually mean ? Are they per second, minute or something else ? 
You thus need to provide more details. If it it the case that these are the total absolute numbers, then there is something wrong with your setup. Because even if you run just one consumer, it should consume from all the partitions, just that it might take longer.

The way Kafka works is that it will assign partitions to consumers inside the group (one consumer might consume from multiple partitions , however one partition is always assigned to one consumer).

Comment: Thanks Manav for taking your time. Consumer Threads was left until it got timed out consumertimeoutexception. The numbers are just count of records and has nothing to do with time taken. These are absolute numbers. My consumer code is much similar to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the consumer timeout helped in consuming all the messages . Thanks To Manav, there was indeed some latency in the consumer and when I increased the timeout, it worked.